# Angular-ui and how to bind modal form inputs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm learning AngularJS currently and am just playing with ui-bootstrap.

I've created a simple modal with a form and I'm trying bind to the attributes on the main page (the page from which the modal is called).

For example, update the name in the modal and the attr. in the background are updated.

Can't get my head around why it doesn't work. The modal is called from the same controller and the attributes within the modal are updated.

My modal looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="LocationsCtrlGet">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal for {{ location.location_name }}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form ng-submit="save(location)" ng-model='location'>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <input ng-model="location.location_name" class='form-control' placeholder='Location name'>
      ...
```

In my main page:

```
<div ng-controller="LocationsCtrlGet">
  {{ location.location_name }}
    <p ng-click="open('small')" class='btn btn-default btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-edit fa-sm'></i>Edit</p>
</div>
```

And the controller:

```
app.controller('LocationsCtrlGet', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$modal', 'Location',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $modal, Location) {

  $scope.location = Location.get({id: $routeParams.id}, function(data) {
    $scope.loading = false
  })

  $scope.open = function (size) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'partials/locations/editLocationModal',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      size: size
    });
    ...
```

If I put the form in the main html, it works fine. And, like I said, it updates the attributes in the modal.

Answer (score -1):

You should be binding to the fields to the scope of your ModalInstanceCtrl not your LocationsCtrl.

In your modal view, you have ng-controller directive and a controller defined $modal.open() method. remove the ng-controller directive.

```
<div>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal for {{ location.location_name }}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form ng-submit="save(location)" ng-model='location'>
    <div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <input ng-model="location.location_name" class='form-control' placeholder='Location name'>
  ...
```

In your example you didn't post your ModalInstanceCtrl. In this you should have the action for submitting the form.

Comment: Ok. Would you be able to post an example pls?

Comment: I have posted an example of the view. Please update your example to include the ModalInstanceCtrl, this is the controller you will bind  your fields to.

Comment: Actually the problem was that I was calling from a template in a directive. When I put on the page it worked fine. Don't really understand why it didn't work yet but will figure that later.